# Flutter get logged user data to other screen view

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have API.dart like this to authenticating a user, log in and log out

```
class Api {


static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

  Api(FirebaseUser user) {
    this.firebaseUser = user;
  }

  static Future<FBApi> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);

    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
//    print('photoURL api ' + user.photoUrl);
    return Api(user);
  }

  static Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut().then((_) {
      print("***** log out...what the hell?");
      _googleSignIn.signOut();
    });
  }
}
```

I've have a cloud function to create new user to database cloud firestore.
And in view account settings, I want to update user information like displayName, photoUrl into firestore. How I get current user in my account setting view.

```
class Settings extends StatelessWidget {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'ACCOUNT',
          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new SettingsScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new SettingsScreenState();
}

class SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  TextEditingController controllerNickname;

  SharedPreferences prefs;

  String id;
  String nickName;
  String photoUrl;

  bool isLoading = false;
  File avatarImageFile;

  final FocusNode focusNodeNickname = new FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readLocal();
  }

  void readLocal() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
    nickName = prefs.getString('nickName') ?? '';
    photoUrl = prefs.getString('photoUrl') ?? '';

    controllerNickname = new TextEditingController(text: nickName);

    // Force refresh input
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        avatarImageFile = image;
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    uploadFile();
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    String fileName = id;
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(avatarImageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot;
    uploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        storageTaskSnapshot = value;
        storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
          photoUrl = downloadUrl;
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .document(id)
              .updateData({'displayName': nickName, 'photoUrl': photoUrl}).then((data) async {
            await prefs.setString('photoUrl', photoUrl);
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Upload success");
          }).catchError((err) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
          });
        }, onError: (err) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
    });
  }

  void handleUpdateData() {
    focusNodeNickname.unfocus();

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(id)
        .updateData({'displayName': nickName, 'photoUrl': photoUrl}).then((data) async {
      await prefs.setString('nickname', nickName);
      await prefs.setString('photoUrl', photoUrl);

      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });

      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Update success");
    }).catchError((err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });

      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`

This returns the current user if any. Otherwise it returns `null`

Comment: Thanks for your susgestion. I'm using shared_preferences plugin but I'm not interested. Howerver, I using `FirebaseAuth.instance.getCurrentUser()` is not found. just `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`.

Comment: Like this? @Robin

`String email ;
  String displayName;
  String photoUrl;

  void _userInfo() async {
    final currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
      email = email = currentUser.uid;
      displayName = currentUser.displayName;
      photoUrl = currentUser.photoUrl;
    }
  }`

Comment: Indeed the get should be omitted.

Comment: New issue: I can't not assign current user into view

`invalid argument` when I assign currentUser.displayName for user variable and put into Text

`Another exception was thrown: 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 48 pos 16: 'imageUrl != null': is not true.` when I assign currentUser.photoUrl for photoUrl

Comment: I wouldn't know. I haven't used that dependency. Something is null.